# How can I drag an drop rows from a section to another UITableView section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop

Here is my code where I drag and drop rows into the same UITableview section. I've created the array hiddenOrderList.

```
var displayedOrderList = [CarouselOrder]()
var hiddenOrderList = [CarouselOrder]()
```

I want to drag and drop rows from the first section to the another one.

```
func tableView(_: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return displayedOrderList.count
    case 1:
        return hiddenOrderList.count
    default:
        return 1
    }
}
```

Below, I've created the custom cell for my first section :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SRCarouselOrderTableViewCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SRCarouselOrderTableViewCell
        cell.configureCell(name: displayedOrderList[indexPath.row].name!, image: (categoryEnum(rawValue: displayedOrderList[indexPath.row].category!)?.getIconCategory())!)
        return cell
}
```

I can drag and drop rows into the same section but I want to drag and drop to the other section. When I drag and drop to the other section, the app crash with "Fatal error: Index out of range" message.

```
func tableView(_: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedObject = displayedOrderList[sourceIndexPath.row]

    displayedOrderList.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    hiddenOrderList.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view

see this